# Replacing Array Elements by using pointer byreference in C++

Tags: c++

I want to replace an array element with other values by reference. But I am facing problem while doing this. My code is below. In the below code I am only getting the last value which is 10 after passing by reference. But I want to get the changed value like 6,7,8,9,10. Please suggest:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

 int temp=6;
 int byreference (int *x){
   for (int t=0;t<5;t++){
     *x=temp+t;     
   }
}



int main ()
{   
    int array[5];

    for (int s=0;s<5;s++){
        array[s]=s+1;
        byreference(&array[s]);
        cout<<*&array[s]<<endl;
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are using c++ why not use `std::vector<int>`?

Comment: Using the above code, I do not have any problem to create array. The problem that I am facing is to replace the values. It is showing only the last value from the function which is 10. But i want to show 6,7,8,9,10

Comment: why using loop in `byreference`? only last change will be visible, why others?

Comment: Yeah but you should consider changing anyway, i mean `*&array[s]`, this is a terrible way to write code.

Comment: yeah drop the *& just use array[s]

Comment: Rakibul Hasan how to show all the changes then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without vector:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int temp=6;
int byreference (int *x){
for (int t=0;t<5;t++){
    *(x+t)=temp+t;     
}
}

int main ()
{   
    int array[5];

    for (int s=0;s<5;s++){
        array[s]=s+1;
        byreference (array);
        cout<<array[s]<<endl;
    }

}
```

output:

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

Answer (score 1):

You would be much better off using stl types if you are going to use `c++`:

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

const int temp=6;
int byreference (std::vector<int> &x){
    for (int t = 0; t<x.size(); t++){
        x[t] = temp + t;  
    }
}

int main ()
{   
    std::vector<int> array(5, 0);

    for (int s = 0; s < array.size(); s++) {
        array[s]=s+1;
        byreference(array);
        cout << array[s] << endl;
    }
}
```

output:

```
6
7
8
9
10
```

This way you avoid problems like running over the ends of your arrays.

Comment: Getting the errors below:$$ In function ‘int byreference(std::vector<int>&) $$error: no match for ‘operator*’ in ‘*x’

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
*x=temp+t;
```

makes sure that all the values in `array` are set to `10`.

Why?

`temp` is set to `6` and is not being changed in the program.

In the loop,

```
for (int t=0;t<5;t++)
{
    *x=temp+t;  
}
```

`*x` is being set and reset until `t=4`. Then it stops. At that time `*x = 6+4 = 10`.

If you want the array to have `6, 7, 8, ...`, you can change `byreference` to:

```
void byreference (int *x)
{
    *x += temp-1;
}
```